# Sonos event subscription without cloud service to receive events

Tags: sonos

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to subscribe to events in the new Sonos API for an iOS app.

It seems like a cloud service is needed to receive events from the Sonos Cloud.
As described here:

- [[Subscribing to events with Sonos API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189170/subscribing-to-events-with-sonos-api])
- [https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/connect]

Is there any way for an iOS app to subscribe to events (volume and grouping change) **without** having to run a cloud service?

If not, any features based on event subscriptions will not be able to work if there is trouble connecting to the cloud for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to run without a cloud service. You must have a reliable cloud service for events and subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Each device also has a super fast / local / undocumented, UPNP service that also supports events.
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64606904/639153) should give you some pointers on how to get it working in node.

In a nutshell:

1. Setup an http endpoint on the device (not sure how that works in Swift)
2. [Tell (in node)](https://github.com/svrooij/node-sonos-ts/blob/c1f56796f1489774beb2fbd4ca862619d8e4510a/src/services/base-service.ts#L324-L350) the speaker to start sending events for a specific service
3. Handle the received XML events.

Sample event from `RenderingControlService` (yes it has nested encoded xml in the `<LastChange>` property):

```xml
<e:propertyset xmlns:e="urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0"><e:property><LastChange>&lt;Event xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/&quot;&gt;&lt;InstanceID val=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;Volume channel=&quot;Master&quot; val=&quot;15&quot;/&gt;&lt;Volume channel=&quot;LF&quot; val=&quot;100&quot;/&gt;&lt;Volume channel=&quot;RF&quot; val=&quot;100&quot;/&gt;&lt;Mute channel=&quot;Master&quot; val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;Mute channel=&quot;LF&quot; val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;Mute channel=&quot;RF&quot; val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;Bass val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;Treble val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;Loudness channel=&quot;Master&quot; val=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&lt;OutputFixed val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;HeadphoneConnected val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;SpeakerSize val=&quot;3&quot;/&gt;&lt;SubGain val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;SubCrossover val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;SubPolarity val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;SubEnabled val=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&lt;SonarEnabled val=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&lt;SonarCalibrationAvailable val=&quot;1&quot;/&gt;&lt;PresetNameList val=&quot;FactoryDefaults&quot;/&gt;&lt;/InstanceID&gt;&lt;/Event&gt;</LastChange></e:property></e:propertyset>
```

Comment: Yes, this I believe is the "legacy" UPNP interface, which is superseded by the new cloud-based interface.
This works very well, but not on the S2 platform being rolled out on all new and many old Sonos devices.
For now, I have abandoned my project, not wanting to have a variable-cost cloud service in the mix... doesn't fit the business model I had in mind for a 3rd party controller app.

Comment: It still works on the new S2 devices, many of our users confirmed that. The old UPNP interface is still used by their own app so it will probably be around for many years to come.